# Copying Features from multiple sources

Tags: python, features, loop, copy

I'm new to Python and trying to automate copying specified features from a bunch of nested geodatabases into a new geodatabase- script seems to work ok, except for the copying features part (the 2 lines commented out below) .

```
import os
import arcpy

top_folder = r"W:\Gisdata\Fish\Proj\Bathymetry"
output = r"D:\Fish\PROJ\Bathy\test\testmrg.gdb"
bathshore = []

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(top_folder):
    for d in dirs:
        if not d.endswith(".gdb"):
            continue
        gdb_path = os.path.join(path, d)

        arcpy.env.workspace = gdb_path
        all_fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
        for fds in arcpy.ListDatasets('','feature'):
            for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('','',fds):
                all_fcs.append(fc)

        for a in all_fcs:
            if '_shore' in a:
##                arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(a, output+"sh")
##                bathshore.append(a)
                print "Exported %s" % a


print "Exported the following feature classes %s" % bathshore
```